# Is it possible to use NSUserDefaults (ex. to save login info) in a TVML application?

Tags: swift, swift2, tvos, tvml

I love the simplicity of the Client-Server applications and their templates as it fits with the type of application I intend to create.

However, my application will require access to an external API which requires authentication (username and password). I understand that it is not possible to save data in tvOS applications but is it possible to use NSUserDefaults to store text?

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use NSUserDefault inside the App (you can bridge the access using JSExport) or you can use localStorage (W3C) in the Javascript code.

`localStorage` works in the same way as a web page, and it is preferable than the other option.